# Something to the power of a logarithm

Tags: logarithms, exponentiation

This is probably a very obvious question, but here goes...

An answer in my textbook claims that

$$3^{\log n} = n^{\log 3}$$

and that

$$4n^2 (3/4)^{\log n} = 4n^{\log 3}$$

Why, using more basic laws, is this the case?

(Unfortunately Google confuses this question with changing bases, exponentiation being the inverse of log (which is of course related), and similar matters.)

Comment: $3^{\log n} = e^{\log n\cdot \log 3}$, and $n^{\log 3} = e^{\log 3\cdot \log n}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint : $a=b$ implies $\log a=\log b$ and $\log a^b=b\log a$

Answer (score 4):

Recall that $3 = b^{\log_b 3}$.

Therefore $3^{\log_b n} = \Big(b^{\log_b 3}\Big)^{\log_b n} = b^{(\log_b 3)(\log_b n)} = \Big(b^{\log_b n}\Big)^{\log_b 3} = n^{\log_b 3}$.

Answer (score 2):

Change basis:

$$3^{\log n}=3^{\frac{\log_3n}{\log_3e}}=\left(3^{\log_3n}\right)^{\frac{1}{\log_3e}}=n^{1/\log_3e}=n^{\log 3}$$